# libcurl easy_perform crashing

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am using libcurl easy mode trying to send a request. Followed the example code but getting a seg fault:

```
 curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);  
CURL *easyhandle = curl_easy_init();                                                                 

        //allow no certificates                                                                              
        curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);                                            

        //give lib curl the URL                                                                              
        curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_URL, urlString);                                                

        //set the callback                                                                                   
        curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &routingCallback);                               

        res = curl_easy_perform(easyhandle);                                                                 


        //clean up the easy handle                                                                           
        curl_easy_cleanup(easyhandle);
```

Then when I debug in GDB:

```
Starting program: /home/michaelamici/Documents/bbb/hrouter 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff2a02700 (LWP 3829)]
[Thread 0x7ffff2a02700 (LWP 3829) exited]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x6) at malloc.c:2949
2949      if (chunk_is_mmapped (p))                       /* release mmapped memory. */
(gdb)
```

I am positive that the URL is correct because I am getting response from curl CLI

Comment: You never check return values for error conditions so you get what you get. I suggest using a debugger to step through the code and examine what's actually going on.

Comment: Welcome to c, where every function call takes at least 4 lines to safely.

Comment: Probably has something to do with `routingCallback`. But diagnosing it with this code is just guesswork. What we need is a minimal compiling example that exhibits the issue (you will probably find the problem while creating the `minimal compiling example`).